# Convert ONE row with multiple values to MULTIPLE columns with single value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT SUM(idHit = 122791), SUM(idHit = 950521) FROM hits
```

that returns two values, instead of only one row with two columns:

```
5, 7
```

Using mysql syntax, I would like to get both values in one column with two rows? Like

```
5
7
```

That´s all, I suppose is necessary to convert sql query to subquery, but not sure. Please HELP.

Comment: If your issue involves just two results, you could try running select of the first **UNION** select of the second. If, on the other hand, this is just an example and you may have several results (say, 3 or more), you need to **PIVOT** your result. You may find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT idHit, COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE idHit IN (122791, 950521)
GROUP BY idHit;
```

If you have a problem where both may not exist, then I would suggest `left join`:

```
select ids.idhit, count(t.idhit)
from (select 122791 as idhit union all select 950521) ids left join
     t
     on t.idhit = ids.idhit
group by ids.idhit;
```

The `union all` is an interesting approach.  I would phrase it as:

```
SELECT 122791, COUNT(*) FROM hits WHERE idHit = 122791
UNION ALL
SELECT 950521, COUNT(*) FROM hits WHERE idHit = 950521;
```

Note only is this standard SQL, but it can make use of an index if one is available.

Comment: Don´t works. 1. Return only one value because idHit 950521 don´t exist in table HITS. 2. I need to maintain INTACT the original query: SELECT SUM(idHit = 122791), SUM(idHit = 950521) FROM hits , but is posible to use results in a subquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with UNION

```
SELECT SUM(idHit = 122791) FROM hits
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(idHit = 950521) FROM hits
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but it generates two querys, so it is less efficient, meanwhile, """ SELECT SUM(idHit = 122791), SUM(idHit = 950521) FROM hits """ is an efficient UNIQUE QUERY. Please, reduce the problem to convert the inicial results "5, 7" in only one row, to 5 AND 7 in two separated rows. I need efficient because the real query return thousands of values. Thank you very very much.